# Is Yo-Yo's power actually tied to her heartrate?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of SHIELD*, Elena "Yo-Yo" Rodriguez explains that she can use her powers to move at super speeds for the duration of "one heartbeat" before she snaps back to her starting location.

Is this a literal explanation of her powers, or is it a rough approximation?

i.e.: If she has an accelerated heart rate, does she have a more limited amount of time to move versus when she is calm?

Note: answers based on the comic version of her are acceptable if there is nothing definite from the MCU version.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find anything other than her own testimony.

> Daisy: How do your powers work?
> Elena [speaking through Joey Gutierrez]: It is connected to [my] pulse.
> Mac: What does that mean, what is the radius of [your] powers?
> Elena [speaking through Joey Gutierrez]: As far as [I] can go in one heartbeat.

In Marvel's Agents of Shield 'Slingshot' [Episode 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjwQFLguIeI), Simmons takes Yo-Yo's pulse and says "you're a regular hummingbird aren't you."

Maybe her heart was racing because she was running the search and didn't want Fitz or Simmons to see, or maybe her heart rate is always super fast as a result of her powers.

The [DC Heroes RPG](http://www.writeups.org/slingshot-marvel-comics-secret-warriors/#stats) says this:

> When her power first manifested, as soon as she stopped running Slingshot was yanked back to her starting point at the same speed.
>
> It’s unclear whether this is still an issue which she’s learned to deal with, but if you wish to assume so, Superspeed has the Limitation that she’s always forced directly back to her starting point once she stops running.

**At least in the comics, she powers work until she stops running, in which case she was slung back to her starting point.**